# How to bind multiple events together to "this"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
this.eventChange = this.eventChange.bind(this);
this.buttonClick3 = this.buttonClick3.bind(this);
this.eventChange1 = this.eventChange1.bind(this);
```

How to bind more than one event handlers to this function together?
If I've many event handler functions like this, how to do it? Any option?

Comment: You could put it in an array and loop, but it seems like a pointless “optimization”. If you have so many event handlers that this even seems like a “good” idea I’d argue your component has larger issues than this.

Comment: There are proposed changes in JS that we can remove that. But the browser support is limited now. https://medium.com/@nikolalsvk/loosing-bind-this-in-react-8637ebf372cf

Comment: One option is having a loop. Another one is going with an arrow function where this already bound. But I also think as @DaveNewton mentioned, you need to rethink you component structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming those calls are placed in the constructor you could use [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) which will automatically be bound to this current instance when using an arrow function.

```
class Something {
  buttonClick = (...args) => {
    // code that uses `this` ...
  };
}
```

The above code would allow you to skip the `this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)` binding.

Be aware that using public class fields is less efficient than a normal function, since they are bound on instance level instead of prototype level. So I would advise you to only use this when you are binding a function to the current instance context anyway. Don't replace all your functions with this approach.

---

If you aren't using a transpiler like Babel or you can't use this stage 3 feature for another reason. The alternative is looping through a predefined array, which contains the methods that need to be bound.

```
const methodsToBind = ["buttonClick", "eventChange", "buttonClick3", "eventChange1"];
methodsToBind.forEach(method => this[method] = this[method].bind(this));
```